# Calcular a média

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa Tarde!
Prezados preciso calcular a media dessa coluna calculada.

```
SELECT 
RESUMO.CODCOLIGADA,
RESUMO.ID_CCUSTO,
RESUMO.CODCCUSTO,
RESUMO.NOME,
RESUMO.DTBAIXA,
SUM (RECEITAS) AS RECEITAS,
SUM(CUSTO)     AS CUSTO,
***SUM (RECEITAS) +  SUM(CUSTO) + SUM(IMPOSTOVENDAS) AS 'RESULTADO OPR' ,***
```

calcular a media desse coluna RESULTADO OPR
Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Já tentou `AVG(RECEITAS + CUSTO + IMPOSTOVENDAS)`?

Comment: A média é em relação ao que ? A linha do Group by ? em sql AVG fornece a média mas ao menos para mim a pergunta não ficou clara.

Answer (score -2):

, ('RESULTADO OPR'/3) as MEDIAOPR

Basta adicionar, o calculo de média é total/fatores se a média são sempre dos 3 fatores, é só dividir por 3